# Autowired is null in Spring

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a class `TestServiceImpl` which is annoted with `@Service` and `@EnabledTransactionManagement` annotation.
I am refering 2 DAO objects in it `@Autowired Service1DAO s1` and `@Autowired Service2DAO s2`. The `Service1DAO` and `Service2DAO` classes are annoted with `@Repository` annotation.
The methods are annoted with `@Trasanction` and required parameters according to requirement.

The questio is:
I am able to get `s1` object but when I am trying to get the `s2` object it is showing me null.
They are defined one by another.

The serivie class is:

```
@Service 
@Scope("prototype")
@EnabledTransactionManagement 
public class TestServiceImpl {
    @Autowired Service1DAO s1; 
    @Autowired Service2DAO s2;

    @Transation(readOnly = false, propogation = Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW)
    public String getXXX1(){
        s1.print();
    }

    @Trsanction(readOnly = false, propogation = Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW)`enter code here`
    public String getXXX2(){
        s2.write();
    }
}
```

DAO classes are:

```
@Repository
public class Service1DAO implements Service1{
    @PersistentContext
    EntityManager em;

    public String Print(){
        em.XXXXXX();
    }
}

@Repository
public class Service2DAO implements Service2{
    @PersistentContext
    EntityManager em;

    public String write(){
        em.XXXXXX();
    }
}
```

The xml contains the component scan pakcage mentioned.

Comment: The  methods in service class are annoted with @Trasanction.

Comment: Please add the code

Comment: When and How are you trying to access the s2 object? Is it by a controller or are you creating an object? Can you let us know how are you doing that?

Comment: 1 - It is better to inject your dependencies on services

Comment: 2 - to debug, inject ApplicationContext and do getBeans to see list of services that are available

Comment: could you please show the exception message and code from where you are using service obj

Comment: When I am accessing the service class from my controller class. 
If I called the print() its working fine for Service1DAO but when I am trying to access write() method, the exception is NullPointerException on s2 object. 
But when I am  creating the same Service2DAO object on other service class and autowire the object, its map the object and working as expected.
Even I was trying to get s2 object using @Resource annotation but it wont work.

Comment: You should be programming to interfaces `Service1` and `Service2` not the actual implementations. Due to the `@Transactional` spring creates a proxy that implements the interface and wraps the actual class in that proxy.

Comment: I got your point, need to annote interfaces Service1 and Service2 with the annotation @Repository. Clear me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... The error has been resolved.

The Service class object created in controller using new() and I was looking those in service and dao classes. It was mistake related to code implementation, even using Spring still follow the path of java to create a object.